# Linux Mint 9 Virtualenv ImportError for zlib and PYTHONPATH is empty?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, zlib, linux-mint

I'm running Mint 9 and I can't get Virtualenv to run. Every time I run it I get an ImportError for zlib, while the Software Manager claims both zlib1g-dev and zlib1g are installed.

One interesting thing is that there's no PYTHONPATH environment variable set. Is this typical and could it be the problem why zlib can't be found?

Edit:

I also did confirm that it really wasn't available from a standard Python prompt. How do I ensure libraries are available within Python?

Edit:

Ok I found the problem, I was trying to use Python 2.7 and the default for the distro is 2.6. The zlib libraries seem to only be installed into Python 2.6. How do I get them into 2.7 also?

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv doesn't export a `PYTHONPATH`, instead `VIRTUAL_ENV` is exported, then the `sys.path` thing is handled by `site` module.

The `zlib` is in the standard library, and it's configured to be enabled by default, so I guess you didn't have zlib-dev installed.

try:

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

and recompile yr python2.7.